# Firebase/nodejs auto refresh view after database updates

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like use nodeJS to refresh my view, every time a function has made changes to the firebase database. My current code is

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    res.render('list',{ data:snapshot.val() })
});
```

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Code is working fine but Its not auto updating my view. If i connect to same application from 2 different browser(clients) and if first user make some changes in application that are not visible to another client untill he refresh browser

Comment: also  ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    res.render('list',{ data:snapshot.val() })
}); giving error headers already sent

Comment: From the last error message you mention, it looks like your `on("value"` callback is being invoked correctly. Aside from that, there is not enough information in the question to see what's going wrong.

Comment: my question is using above structure of code that i have written does firebase make application real time ?

Comment: You are running this on a node-server, so `res` is a response object? In that case, this will send the response to your client. But what that client does with it, is up to you. In most Firebase app, the client connects directly to the database and updates its UI from within the `ref.on("value"`.

Comment: Yes res is response object and i am using ejs to display front end . So basically i am fetching data stored in firebase and sending to EJS template on ref.on('value') event but still its not making my EJS template realtime . so on particular GET request i have written router.get(/getdata){ //code to fetch data , ref.on('value'){ res.resnder('EJSPAGE',fetchedData)  } .       Is it possible to do so ?